# In Kotlin why do we capture a value in closure

Tags: kotlin, generics

```
DropdownMenu(expanded = ddMenu.value, onDismissRequest = {ddMenu.value = false} )
                    {
                        DropdownMenuItem(text = { Text("Çıkış") },onClick = {})
                    }
```

In expanded we didnt capture the value in closure but in onDismissRequest we did.I know it's about not returning a value but I dont understand how this statement "boolean.value = false" could return a value ? And if its so why did we use Unit ? Performance ?

Comment: You should learn kotlin firstly from guides, not from stack overflow. This is a place to help, not teach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know it's about not returning a value

It's not. The use of braces `{ }` here means this is a lambda expression. Lambda expressions evaluate to values just like the simpler expression `ddMenu.value`. The difference is that the value of a lambda expression is a *function* (it's a value of type function), whereas the value of the expression `ddMenu.value` is a `Boolean`.

I highly suggest you read the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html) about higher-order functions and lambdas.

> I dont understand how this statement "boolean.value = false" could return a value

It doesn't. If you look into `DropdownMenu`'s declaration, you'll probably see that the `onDismissRequest` parameter has a type like `() -> Unit` or `(Something) -> Unit`. This is what defines a [function type](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#function-types) (what's in the parentheses is the list of argument types, and after the arrow is the return type). Returning `Unit` is the Kotlin way to represent a function doesn't return anything of interest (it's also called a `void` function in some languages), which is the reason why your lambda expression `{ ddMenu.value = false }` doesn't need to return anything. Implicitly, it's as if you had written:

```kotlin
{
    ddMenu.value = false
    Unit
}
```

(the last expression is what the lambda returns when it's called).

> why do we capture a value in closure

This is where it gets interesting. Because lambdas are *functions*, the code inside the lambda is not executed when you construct the lambda. It's executed at some later time, whenever someone *invokes* the function. So, in `DropdownMenu`'s code, somewhere, you will likely find `onDismissRequest.invoke()` or `onDismissRequest()` (with just parentheses, which is the syntactic shortcut for [the `invoke()` operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/operator-overloading.html#invoke-operator)).

This has some implications. Namely, all variables that are used in the body of the lambda, and that were visible at the time the lambda was declared (such as `ddMenu` here), might no longer be visible in the scope where the function is actually invoked. This is why lambdas *capture* such variables in a way that's available later. This combination of some function code + some data about its environment / captured variables is called a *closure*.

Comment: II learned a lot from the article thank you but I still dont get the one part that the reason is not executing the code when we construct it.Is it about performance ?

Comment: It's not about performance, but it's about what it does. You really don't want to set `ddMenu.value = false` at the moment you build the `DropdownMeny` component. You want that to happen when the component is dismissed. This is why you pass a *function* to `DropDownmenu`. It's a piece of code that you want to run only when the menu is dismissed. And the component allows you to pass a snippet of code via this `onDismissRequest` function parameter